# Затруднения с обработкой ввода оверлеем

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть главная `ViewModel`, которая порождает, и частично управляет ими.

Проблема в следующем, все рожденные модели ссылаются на одно и тоже поле/команду(ы), от такого есть какой-то толк, т.к. они все ссылаются на один код, который срабатывает именно при вызове `callback'ов`, а именно за управление оверлеем.
В любой момент исполнения программы есть шанс, что хоть одна из порожденных `View`, вызовет этот `callback`, и оверлей будет открыт. В этот момент происходит передача управления оверлею, и блокировка контента расположенного под ним, с запретом установки фокуса, и вообще отключается пользовательский ввод. Далее, при этом, окно (оно же родительское `View`) продолжает принимать пользовательский ввод, и закрытие оверлея по нажатию <kbd>ESC</kbd> становится нереальным, теперь что бы закрыть оверлей, пользователю придется тянуться мышью до кнопки закрытия.

Как можно сделать так, что бы передалось не только управление а еще и обработка пользовательского ввода на оверлей?

Comment: А какую сущность вы именуете оверлеем?

Comment: «частично управляет ими» — кем управляет?

Comment: Установите фокус на ваш оверлей (проверьте, что у него Focusable = true), тогда он будет принимать пользовательский ввод.